# How to avoid most recent updated nodes while retrieving in neo4j?

Tags: performance, sorting, neo4j

This might be a strange question related to the database's core features, but I got stuck with this because of a performance issue.

Consider the following scenario :

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n:Label1) 
WHERE n.prop1<1484850600 
OR (n.prop1=1484850600 AND n.prop2<2)
WITH n 
LIMIT 10 
RETURN n
```

The situation is like I update prop1 and prop2 after performing above query 
*(if n.prop1<1484850600 then [prop1=1484850600, prop2=1] and n.prop1=1484850600 AND n.prop2<2 then [prop2=prop2+1])*

But when I perform the above query again I will obviously get the records of (prop1=1484850600) first, which are not required for me (I need other nodes which are not updated).

I can achieve it by sorting id (which is auto-incremented value of that node), But As I was having huge data-set(1cr of nodes, sorting of 1cr property values) that cypher query is producing and it is taking more time than usual, So I stuck here.

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n:Label1) 
WHERE n.prop1<1484850600 
OR (n.prop1=1484850600 AND n.prop2<2)
WITH n 
ORDER BY n.id 
LIMIT 10 
RETURN n
```

Is there any other way to achieve it or did I miss anything?

Comment: What is the `n.prop2` value when `n.prop1` set to `1484850600`?

Comment: prop2 value is 0 or 1 and while setting prop1 to 1484850600, I'll also set prop2 to 1, I've updated my question regarding this

Answer (score 1):

Split the query into two. Deal with the nodes that have prop1 = 1484850600 and prop2 < 2. Then do a second query to deal with nodes that have prop1 < 1484850600.

Comment: Actually I did split the query into two parts, but before that I want to get those nodes which are not updated.
WITH COLLECT(n) AS rows
[a IN rows WHERE a.sOn < 1484850600] AS less_than_rows, 
[b IN rows WHERE b.sOn = 1484850600 AND b.setC < 2] AS other_rows;
My problem is with rotating nodes, by avoiding recently updated nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to have a property that stores the flag `has been updated`. Something like this:

```
MATCH (n:Label1) 
  WHERE n.hasUpdated = FALSE AND
        (n.prop1<1484850600 OR (n.prop1=1484850600 AND n.prop2<2))
WITH n LIMIT 10 
  SET n.hasUpdated=TRUE,
      n.prop1=1484850600,
      n.prop2=n.prop2+1
RETURN n
```

Comment: But I need to add extra property to over 1cr of nodes and index it.

Comment: Before that I think I'll miss the second condition(n.prop1=1484850600 AND n.prop2<2) because n.hasUpdated=TRUE. So this will not fulfill requirement

Answer (score 0):

A variation on stdob--'s idea, maybe you can use another label here.

Either you can run a separate query to add an :Unprocessed label to all the nodes you want to process, include the checking of the :Unprocessed label as you match on nodes to process, and remove the label as you process them.

You could instead use an inverted approach, start without any new label, match where the node doesn't have the :Processed label, and set the :Processed label as you process the nodes.

It may also be useful to batch your processing using APOC Procedures. See [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) and [apoc.periodic.commit()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit).